# How can you override typescript AMD require functionality?

Tags: typescript, requirejs, require

I have an import for my typescript class

`import Service = require("domain/Service");`

I want to be able to override "require" and basically `toLowercase()` any path that is passed in.

I have added breakpoints in requirejs but it does not seem to be called for each of my imports. I am now wondering if my assumption about requirejs being the underlying module loader is incorrect and fear `require` in typescript may be something in typescript itself?

Either way, can I override `require` in typescript to formalise the casing for my paths?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this out in the end.

The require statements translate to a define in the JS.

When I realised this it was a simple case of intercepting the arguments and lower-casing the paths before they get passed onto the define method.

Something like this (using lodash / underscore) :

```
var _define = define;
    define = function()
    {
        var paths = arguments[0];

        var newPaths = _.map(paths,
            function(path) {
                return path.toLowerCase();
            });

        arguments[0] = newPaths;
        return _define.apply(this, arguments);
    }
```